# Difference between "beyond his knowledge" and "above his head"

Tags: expressions

What is the difference between these expressions:

The explanation I gave him is ...

1. "beyond his knowledge"
2. "above his head"

Comment: Welcome to ELL.SE! I assume you mean to compare these in a context. If so, [please everyone, details. Please.](http://meta.ell.stackexchange.com/questions/439/please-everyone-details-please).

Comment: see edited question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> beyond his knowledge;

Means more than one knows whereas

> above his head means that something is being placed above one’s head (Eg. Damocles’ sword).

If you think of the meaning:

> more than one can handle then the expression would be:
>
> over one’s head.